# Using ManyToManyFields() with Django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I'm building a social network where user are supposed to be able to follow each other. So I define a class user with a field: ManyToMany to stock the users that follow this user. This is what I have done in my **model.py**:

```
followings = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
```

This is my **view.py**:

```
@login_required
def follow_test(request):
    name = request.POST.get('name', '')
    user_followed = Dater.objects.get(username=name)
    current_user = Dater.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    print current_user.followings # display my_app.Dater.None
    current_user.followings.add(user_followed)
    print current_user.followings # display my_app.Dater.None
```

I retrieve correctly my users (current (The one who follow someone) and the followed one) but I can't add the followed user in the set followings of the current user. Can you see something I don't do properly in my view?

Comment: You have to save the data, add your models code.

Comment: I have done: current_user.save() but didn't solve the problem

Comment: No, there is no need to save. You haven't really told us what the problem is that you are experiencing, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`followings` is a manager; to show the members of that relationship, you need to call `.all()` on it (or another manager/queryset method like `order_by`).

```
print current_user.followings.all()
```

Comment: I think he want to add a follower and .add doesn't work on m2m fields. Thats his problem?

Comment: No, that is not his problem. `.add()` is the correct way to add members to a many-to-many relationship, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add).

Comment: I want to add a user (dater) to my class (dater) attribute (followings)

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are perfectly right you save my day I've got a dating site for tomorrow to do thanks a lot :) I just try and it display the users correctly